# Braced functional cast to reference type, a hole in the standard or compilers bug?

Tags: c++, casting, language-lawyer, compiler-bug

According to the standard, a braced functional cast always results in a prvalue, [[expr.cast]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.type.conv#2.sentence-3)

> Otherwise, the expression is a prvalue of the specified type whose result object is direct-initialized with the initializer.

Which is hard to interpret when the *specified type* is a reference type, as it may happen in generic programming. Compiler have adopted specific behavior in this case:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct A {
    A ()=default;
    A (const A&);
};

template <class T, class U>
decltype(auto) 
f(U& a) {
    static_assert (std::is_same_v <decltype (T{a}), T>);
    return T{a};
}


#if defined(__clang__) || defined(_MSC_VER)
void g1(A a){
    decltype(auto) v = f<A&>(a); //GCC: error try to bind a prvalue to a non-const lvalue
    static_assert (std::is_same_v <decltype(v), A&>);
}
#endif

void g2(A a){
    decltype(auto) v = f<const A&>(a); //GCC: call the copy constructor of A
                                       //MSVC and Clang: a no op (direct reference binding)
    static_assert (std::is_same_v <decltype(v), const A&>);
}
```

For Clang, GCC and MSVC agree on the fact the `decltype(T{a})` where `T is A&` is of type `A&`. Which means the result is not a prvalue according to decltype specification. So it looks that none of these compilers is standard compliant.

The evaluation of `T{a}` for Clang and MSVC is just a direct reference binding.

GCC refuses to compiles `g1`. The expression `T{a}` construct a copy of `a` and the temporary is then tentatively bound to the result of `T{a}` (this can be seen in the assembly of the explicit instantiation of template h [here](https://godbolt.org/z/hsxHhk)).

Is any compiler right in such a situation? Or is it just a "no diagnostic required" case?

Comment: https://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1521

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Thank you. This issue is open since 2012, do you know why it is not fixed?

Comment: _do you know why it is not fixed?_ No.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [CWG1521](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1521):

> **`T{expr}` with reference types**
>
> According to 8.2.3 [expr.type.conv] paragraph 4,
>
> > Similarly, a *simple-type-specifier* or *typename-specifier* followed by a *braced-init-list* creates a temporary object of the specified type direct-list-initialized (11.6.4 [dcl.init.list]) with the specified *braced-init-list*, and its value is that temporary object as a prvalue.
>
> This wording does not handle the case where `T` is a reference type: it is not possible to create a temporary object of that type, and presumably the result would be an xvalue, not a prvalue.