# decltype on the variable of reference type with curly braces

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, decltype

Consider the following [code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qj7jhO4fHVu869wn):

```
#include <type_traits>

int main() {
    const int& p = 42;
    auto v1 = decltype(p){};
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(v1), int>);
    
    decltype(p) v2{};
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(v2), const int&>);
    // auto v3 = X(const int&)X {};
}
```

Type of `v1` is deduced as `int`. At the same time type of `v2` is expectedly deduced as `const int&`. I think the first step for `v1` could be treated as adding one more type alias `using T = decltype(p);` and then `auto v4 = T{};`. How this expression (`decltype(p){}` or `T{}`) is treated by compiler?  I know that `{}` part is for instantiation, but how the resulting type of `v1` is not a reference type?

Yet another question: is there a way to declare `v3` variable of the same type as `v1` using explicitly noted type `const int&` (instead of `decltype(p)`)?

Any links to standard would be appreciated.

Comment: Couldn't believe `decltype(p){}` compiles, at first. Apparently `{}` value-initializes a temporary `int`, which is then bound to the reference. Huh!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Braced functional cast to reference type, a hole in the standard or compilers bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62325198/braced-functional-cast-to-reference-type-a-hole-in-the-standard-or-compilers-bu)

Comment: _Yet another question_ 1 question per question plz

Comment: Does `const auto& v3 = (const int&){};` answer your `Yet another question: is there a way to declare v3...?`?

Comment: @KamilCuk hmm... I’ve checked on clang, and it doesn’t compile. Works in gcc.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, what would make that syntax (`const auto& v3 = (const int&){};`) behave different from `const int& v3{};`? I mean, what do you need that syntax for?

Comment: @Enlico I just wanted to know how to replicate `decltype(p){}` without `decltype`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(To the downvoter(s): if you downvoted because you think quoting Scott Meyers is not equivalent to quoting the standard, oh well...)

As you can read from *Effective Modern C++* (augmented with the part of the [errata](https://www.aristeia.com/BookErrata/emc++-errata.html) that you can reach by searching for `Case 2:` at that link, and that just makes the following read simpler, but it's not essential to the question):

> If *`ParamType`* is a non-reference [...] if `expr`'s type is a reference, ignore the reference part. If [...] `expr` is `const`, ingore that too. If it's `volatile`, also ignore that.

where `param` is the declaration specifier, which in your case is just `auto`, i.e. a non-reference.

In other words, you're creating `v1` via plain `auto` (not `auto&`), i.e. by copy, so it does not matter whether you are initializing it with an entity which is reference or not, or even with `const` or not (or `volatile` or not, fwiw), because you're copying it.

Think about the simpler case,

```cpp
int i = 3;
int& p = i;
auto v1 = p;
```

as far as `v1` is concerned, it's really not important whether it is initalized with one (`i`) or the other (`p`) name by which the *same* entity is known, because it will get a copy of whatever value that entity has.

`auto` type deduction works just like template type deduction (except for a difference in how they deal with braced initializer, which is not relevant in this case), and for both of them you can refer to Scott Meyers' *Effective Modern C++*.

Answer (score -1):

> `auto v4 = T{}`;. How this expression (`decltype(p){}` or `T{}`) is treated by compiler? I know that `{}` part is for instantiation, but how the result type is not a reference type?

The result `decltype(p){}` *is* a reference type. It's the usage of `auto` that drops the `const` and reference qualifiers. The deduction of the type is explained [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto), and they're the same as those used for template type deduction. You could use `decltype(auto)` instead to keep those qualifiers (or, in this particular case, you could use `const auto&`).

Comment: It also drops `volatile`, if there is, as I explained in my answer.