# Is it allowed to cast to a reference-type with braces?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, language-lawyer

Seems like an academic question, but just wasted an hour trying to understand GCC complaints...

Consider the following code:

```
void foo(int t) {
  using T = int&;
  // Compiles with both clang and gcc:
  T r1(t);
  T r2{t};
  (void)T(t);
  // OK with clang, ERROR in gcc:
  (void)T{t};
}
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/dcv7z6PvT

GCC fails to compile the last line with the error:

`cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'T' {aka 'int&'} to an rvalue of type 'int'`

However, `t` is an l-value, so the error seems at least misleading. Maybe it tries to create a temporary copy of `t` under the hood? Anyway, what is the proper behaviour?

Comment: Dup of [Braced functional cast to reference type, a hole in the standard or compilers bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62325198/braced-functional-cast-to-reference-type-a-hole-in-the-standard-or-compilers-bu)